# Visual Studio 2010 - Print Preview option

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just want to print a cs file. But there is only 'print' button under file menu. Is it possible to see a preview before printing? Does visual studio have this option anywhere?

Comment: Same in Visual-Studio-2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think VS2012 has a "print preview" but you could try the following as a work-around:

- Set your printer to "Microsoft XPS writer"
- Print to this printer, this will produce a file you can preview.
- If you are happy with how it looks in XPS you can print to your normal
  printer in the XPS viewer.

Answer (score 1):

try Me.PrintPreview()

...a simpler and more efficient solution seemingly would be to copy the whole document over to WordPad or a similar text editor it seems...